# UWP C# Windows Phone driving mode

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone

Is there any way to detect when driving mode in Windows Phone 10 is activated using UWP C# app? What I would like to do is to enable extra features in my app whenever user enters driving mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get this information right now (SDK 14393)

Comment: Yeah I found it out, although it is possible to detect Bluetooth connected devices and check if any of the device is the one that should enable driving mode, so it's pretty much the same